# Can't connect to SQL Server setup on Azure VM

Tags: sql-server, azure, virtual-machines

I've got Azure VM setup with SQL Server Express installed.
I can connect with SSMS that's on the VM just fine, but can't connects from my computer.

I've tried this guide, but still can't connect: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4328/access-sql-server-instance-on-azure-vm-using-local-copy-of-management-studio/

Any help would be appreciated, it's odd that Azure doesn't have any documentation for this seemingly simple use case.

Answer (score 0):

The missing piece was UDP 1434. Once I've opened that, everything worked fine.

**Bottom line: both TCP 1433 and UDP 1434 have to be opened in both Azure > Networking and VM Firewall**